# Connecting to Google Fit - New OAuth Consent Screen Error

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

An Android application is trying to connect to Google Fit to upload some data. New OAuth Certificates have recently been added in the Google API Console to handle each flavor of our app since each flavor has a different package name. Users are able to connect to Google Fit and upload our app's data to Google Fit, however, I've ran into some strange issues with the OAuth Consent Screen.

When requesting access to Google Fit, the user is prompted to pick an account to link to Google Fit. Once an account is picked, the OAuth Consent Screen is shown. I recently updated the OAuth Consent Screen info in the Google API Console to have the scopes match the scopes being requested in this particular app. I was surprised and excited that this was no longer one page of permissions but users can now pick and choose which "scope" permissions they want to allow - similar to Apple's Health Kit.

If the user accepts all of the permissions, they are able to connect to Google Fit just fine and data will upload. But if the user does not accept all of the permissions and hits accept, the OAuth Consent Screen will close and then reappear from the beginning and forces the user to go through accepting or denying each "scope" screen all over again. This doesn't happen EVERY time one scope is denied, but happens most of the time.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this? Is there anything that can be done on the app side to fix this?